# Как запретить перемещение view в activity по определенным Y координатам?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

В Activity расположен выдвигающийся снизу view элемент (к примеру height - 300px, а высота всего экрана - 1920px). Как мне запретить его передвижение вверх, при его полном отображении? Т.е. возможно лишь выдвигать его снизу вверх до его полной высоты. 
Разбираюсь с OnTouchListener'ом - непонятны у motionevent'а методы getY и getRawY (в логах пробую отслеживать эти значения при смещении view).

Answer (score 2):

Если выдвижение Вашего view реализуете через анимацию, то можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
public void anim() {
        "Ваше view".animate()
                .y(targetPoint)
                .start();
    }
```

Где `targetPoint` - это желаемое значение координаты `Y`

Относительно получения координат:

`getX` и `getY` возвращает координаты пальца внутри View.

`getRawX` и `getRawY` - возвращает абсолютные экранные координаты.

Comment: Но было бы неплохо увидеть код.